file local "variable must be set at the start of the file"?
Having heard that lexical binding may well become the default in Emacs 31, I wanted to start adding the "lexcial binding cookie" (ie. the lexical-binding: nil file local variable setting) to my Emacs Lisp files. But when I do M-x add-file-local-variable and answer the prompt with "lexical-binding", Emacs says:

user-error: The ‘lexical-binding’ variable must be set at the start of the file

I don't understand, because I am (my cursor is) at the start of the file. What does this mean?

Good question!
Command add-file-local-variable doesn't add the variable as a "cookie" on the first line of the file. Instead, it adds the variable to the file-local list at the end of the file.
Variable lexical-binding needs to be added as a cookie on the first line of the file.
The doc string of that command doesn't make this clear.  The doc string of variable lexical-binding does, however, make it clear:

Unlike other file local variables, this must be set in the first line of a file.

See node Specifying File Variables of the Emacs manual for more info, including how to specify variables on the first line of a file.
It says, for example:

You can use M-x add-file-local-variable-prop-line instead of adding
entries by hand.


I've filed Emacs bug #74267 for this.
